# Dropdown links in Bootstrap 3 stacking horizontally

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have more than one dropdown link for the menu. Everything works fine. But when the screen size is that of a tablet, the dropdown links are not rendered properly. When I click on the first dropdown link "Membership", the dropdownitem " Manage Users" and the next dropdown link "Site Configuration" are rendered side by side horizontally instead of one below the other. Please help.

Added jsfiddle:-
http://jsfiddle.net/u44kj1bk/

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="navbar-text">Welcome, User!</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Membership <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="pull-left dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="/WebLink">Manage Users</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Site Configuration <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="pull-left dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="/">Manage Forums</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/WebLink">Manage Web Links</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Themes <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="pull-left dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="theme-link" datatheme="default" href="#">Day</a></li>
                        <li><a class="theme-link" datatheme="night" href="#">Night</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the `pull-left` class is causing the list items to float to the left, thus stacking horizontally. Remove the classes and this should work.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/aqdyfL9h/1/

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>                        
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="navbar-text">Welcome, User!</li>
                </ul>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Membership <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/WebLink">Manage Users</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Site Configuration <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/">Manage Forums</a></li>
            <li><a href="/WebLink">Manage Web Links</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Themes <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="theme-link" datatheme="default" href="#">Day</a></li>
            <li><a class="theme-link" datatheme="night" href="#">Night</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
            </div>            
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect gillytech... Thanks a ton for the help.

Comment: @vanitha Sure thing. I would like to take this answer a step further and suggest you read this about CSS floats to enhance your skill: http://designshack.net/articles/css/everything-you-never-knew-about-css-floats/